# SessionRevokedError and continously being logged out when I try to access the Telegram-API

Tags: telegram, telethon

I am using the telethon-API to access the telegram-API for some network analysis over multiple groups. As I didn't quite understand how the spam-protection works I tried to test the limits of when telegram stops me from sending requests. I executed the following code-snippet (accidently without an await, so basically 200 requests immediately).

```
for i in range(100):
    client.get_messages(g, limit=None)
    client.get_participants(g)
```

Almost immediately I received an error: `SessionRevokedError: The authorization has been invalidated, because of the user terminating all sessions (caused by GetHistoryRequest)`. I was logged out not only with my application but also on my smartphone and any telegram-web/desktop sessions I had open.

While I could login again on my smartphone, telegram-web and even through the telethon-api, once I send any other request like `client.get_dialogs()`, I was immediately logged out of any device again.

Looking back, it might have been a bad idea but I continued trying logging in and getting kicked in different ways all to the same result.

Today, about 20 hours later I tried logging in again. I was kicked again same as yesterday but now I am quickly kicked out of the smartphone app when I try to enter my phone-number and confirmation (without even accessing any api).

I tried logging in again after multiple hours with enough time for the original requests to have been processed and deleting the `.session`-db from telethon.

I basically have three questions:

1. Anyone has any idea, what happened to my account and if this is just temporary / What I can do to restore it to normal behaviour?
2. Can I somehow check the 'status' of my account, as I don't really understand what exactly is happening to it?
3. Does anyone know of a guide or publications by telegram on how the spam-protection works?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> accidently without an await, so basically 200 requests immediately

This is not how async works in Python. If you don't `await` a call to an `async def`, it won't run at all (unless you had imported the `telethon.sync` hack which puts the `await` for you).

> Anyone has any idea, what happened to my account and if this is just temporary / What I can do to restore it to normal behaviour?

If you're still getting "SessionRevokedError", your account might be compromised, as far as I'm aware, this only occurs when a logged-in client revokes the session. However Telegram may have introduced this error in other circumstances, in which case, no idea.

> Can I somehow check the 'status' of my account, as I don't really understand what exactly is happening to it?

You can message [@SpamBot](https://t.me/SpamBot) or contact support, but that's about it.

> Does anyone know of a guide or publications by telegram on how the spam-protection works?

Telegram can change these limits at any time, and can be based on a lot of conditions that would be impossible to know without reading the server's source code. As long as you don't clearly misuse the API, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! I'm still struggling with the same issue. I've contacted the @SpamBot and it tells me that my account has no restrictions in place. Nevertheless when I run the following code:
`client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)`
`await client.start()`
`dialogs = await client.get_dialogs(limit=10)`

I immediately receive: "telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.SessionRevokedError: The authorization has been invalidated, because of the user terminating all sessions (caused by GetDialogsRequest)"

Comment: I just tried the same code on another device in the same network and it worked without any issues. Maybe Telegram blacklisted this specific device?

Comment: It could be. I am not experienced in these types of limitations.